# ¿Porqué mi Makefile borra los archivos .o cuando compilo?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

Tengo un pequeño proyecto en c que estoy usando para estudiar la complejidad computacional de algoritmos de ordenación. En una carpeta tengo las herramientas que me he hecho para facilitarme la tarea y en otra carpeta tengo unos cuantos ejemplos con algoritmos típicos de ordenación sobre vectores con los que iré trabajando.

El caso es que para poder compilar los ejemplos con las herramientas y almacenar los binarios en carpetas distintas tuve que investigar un poco por internet hasta llegar a este Makefile.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
LIBS=-lm

SRC_DIRS ?= ../lib
BUILD_DIR ?= ../build

SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name '*.c')
OBJS := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIRS)/%.c,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIRS)/%.c
    $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%:  $(OBJS) 
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $@.c -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$@  $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean: 
    $(RM) -r $(BUILD_DIR)

MKDIR_P ?= mkdir -p

print-%  : ; @echo $* = $($*)
```

De esta forma al añadir más ejemplos, pongamos el caso quicksort, solo tengo que programar el algoritmo y compilar el archivo q_sort.c con > make q_sort. El problema viene cuando al final del proceso de compilación me borra los archivos .o de las herramientas, algo que no quiero que ocurra.

```
make shell
mkdir -p ../build/
gcc -Wall -g -c ../lib/c_computacional.c -o ../build/c_computacional.o
mkdir -p ../build/
gcc -Wall -g -c ../lib/v_initializer.c -o ../build/v_initializer.o
gcc ../build/c_computacional.o ../build/v_initializer.o shell.c -o ../build/shell  -lm
--> rm ../build/v_initializer.o ../build/c_computacional.o
```

Normalmente en los Makefile que me encuentro por internet no usan

```
%: $(OBJS)
```

sino que tienen una regla como podría ser

```
q_sort: $(OBJS)
```

me interesa usar % para no tener que tocar el Makefile mientras añado nuevos ejemplos pero con % es cuando me ocurre el problema.


Alguien sabe porqué ocurre esto?


y ya como post creditos si alguien se le ocurre como evitar que se llame por cada objeto?

```
mkdir -p ../build/
```

Llevo demasiadas horas con este Makefile

Comment: ¿Por qué no? Son el resultado de la compilación ¿Acaso quieres quedarte con los archivos de resultados de compilaciones anteriores?

Comment: Cuando compilo un ejemplo, como puede ser q_sport, se genera v_initializer.o y c_computacional.o que luego se usan para compilar el binario q_sport, el comportamiento que no quiero es que me borre los .o cada vez que compilo, aún cuando no he realizado modificaciones en eses archivos.

Comment: Los `.o` son los archivos de resultado de una compilación, si no los borras entre compilaciones es como no compilar.

Comment: Si para compilar un archivo necesito generar previamente 3 archivos de objetos .o, cuando modifico sólo uno de ellos y vuelvo a compilar, se elimina y se genera solo el que he modificado, los otros dos no hace falta volver a compilarlos, el compilador detecta que no han sido modificados y los incluye directamente en el binario resultante. En el caso que describo en mi problema, al final de la compilación me borra todos los archivos de objetos de tal forma que aunque no haya modificado nada en esos archivos el compilador está obligado a volver a generar los, lo que para mí es algo innecesario.

Comment: Pues explícalo bien en tu pregunta, porque con lo que está redactado ahora no se entiende.

Comment: Me parece que se indica cuando Manu FIC-electronica menciona: ...El problema viene cuando al final del proceso de compilación me borra los archivos .o de las herramientas, algo que no quiero que ocurra..

Comment: En el programa (Makefile) que has posteado no hay ninguna instrucción `rm` (hay un `rm -r` qué no es lo invocado). Por tanto no estás mirando al entorno por completo. Es muy posible que intervienen las reglas predefinidas (_built-ins_) de tu instalación de `make` (y qué una de estas reglas siga borrar los `.o`).